# Boost iostreams linking errors regarding zlib

Tags: boost, cmake, clang, iostream, zlib

Windows 10 64bit, using compiler clang-cl and CMake.

I've compiled boost like so:

1 Downloaded zlib source code to `C:/zlib-1.2.12`

2 In file `boost_root/project_config.jam` I added

`using zlib : 1.2.12 : <source>C:/zlib-1.2.12 ;`

3 Compiled iostreams with

`b2.exe toolset=clang-win --with-iostreams -s NO_ZLIB=0 link=shared threading=multi runtime-debugging=off variant=release address-model=64 -a`

4 In CMakeLists for my project used

```
...
find_package(Boost)
target_link_librares(myproj Boost::iostreams zlib)
...
```

5 And built the project, but got linking errors

```
undefined symbol: int const boost::iostreams::zlib::okay
undefined symbol: int const boost::iostreams::zlib::sync_flush
undefined symbol: int const boost::iostreams::zlib::stream_end
undefined symbol: int const boost::iostreams::zlib::default_strategy
undefined symbol: int const boost::iostreams::zlib::deflated
undefined symbol: int const boost::iostreams::zlib::default_compression
```

I tried using precompiled zlib by specifying arguments in `project-config.jam`, but got same linking errors in the end.

Comment: You need to add zlib to your own project's linker inputs (`myproj` target)

Comment: @sehe I added zlib, but same errors arise.

Comment: What is the output of the bootstrap/b2 commands? Around the start it should mention whether ZLIB is actually found. If not, it may just ignore the ZLIB requests

Comment: @sehe If i specify `using zlib : 1.2.12 : <source>C:/zlib_1.2.12_bin ;` in `project-config.jam` file and compile the iostreams lib, at the start it doesn't mention zlib, but does list warnings in files located in `C:/zlib_1.2.12_bin` folder. Also at the end it says "libraries successfully built", and it does generate `z.dll` file in boost_root/stage/lib.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the library exists and is built, you could try adding it manually like:

```
link_directories(${BOOST_ROOT}/stage/lib)
target_link_libraries(myproj z)
```

Looking at my local `FindBoost.cmake` (on a linux machine) I can see this changes:

```
.. versionadded:: 3.7
  ``bzip2`` and ``zlib`` components (Windows only).
```

And much later

```
.. versionadded:: 3.19
  ``bzip2`` and ``zlib`` components on all platforms.
```

It stands to reason that Boost knows how to do these. Indeed on my simple test on linux linking to `Boost::iostreams` component does land me with zlib:

```
find_package(Boost 1.79.0 COMPONENTS iostreams)
target_link_libraries(mytarget Boost::iostreams)
```

Showing

```
ldd build/mutarget
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffef0395000)
        libboost_iostreams.so.1.82.0 => /home/sehe/custom/superboost/stage/lib/libboost_iostreams.so.1.82.0 (0x00007f271cdd9000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f271cb89000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f271cb69000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f271c941000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f271c925000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f271c83c000)
```

Perhaps your version of Cmake, Boost or FindBoost.cmake is too old? Perhaps your Cmake is not finding the right version?

Comment: I manually linked z.lib library, but still same problem. I am using CMake 3.20 with Boost 1.81.0 So they should be up-to-date enough. I checked linking command, it links both iostreams and z.lib libraries. No idea what else to try ...